# TypeError with Python UDF returned inexplicably

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3.3.3

```
def tuplizeDK(x):
from ast import literal_eval
from pandas import isnull
if isnull(x):
    return tuple()
else:
    x = x+','
    return literal_eval(x)
```

The goal is to take an input formatted as a unicode object comprised of either a single numeric ID, or a comma separated list of numeric IDs, and then converting it to a tuple.  The input may be empty though.

Here is what happens:

```
>>> A = '3233'
>>> tuplizeDK(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#188>", line 1, in <module>
    tuplizeDK(A)
  File "./tuplize.py", line 4, in tuplizeDK
    if isnull(x):
TypeError: a float is required
```

But if i just evaluate out of function:

```
>>> isnull(A)

False
```

I am sure that I am missing something simple ... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can't replicate this.

Comment: Also, is this a very simplified version of your code?  Else, wouldn't tuple(A.split(',') if A else '') be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a nicer way to do this, assuming you were planning on apply it to an entire column, is to use one of the vectorised string methods: [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.strings.StringMethods.split.html):

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['a', 'b,c', np.nan, 'd,e,f'])

In [12]: s.str.split(',')
Out[12]: 
0        [a]
1      [b,c]
2        NaN
3    [d,e,f]
dtype: object
```

Comment: This does the trick quite nicely.  One bump though is that even though I am specifying that column as a 'Object': 
`metaFrame[['InverterDKs','ModuleMfg','MeterDK', 'Modulemodel', 'WSDK']]=metaFrame[['InverterDKs','ModuleMfg','MeterDK', 'Modulemodel', 'WSDK']].astype(object)`

it is still interpreting the fields with only a single numeric ID as either floats or ints.  I am not sure on why some are floats and some ints, but that's beside the point.  Is there a cleaner way to do this other than some sort of if statement?